# Can we get the scopes belongs to specific access token?

Tags: linkedin-api

After getting an access token from LinkedIn, we will save it into safe place, but later we need to know which scopes are included in the specific token.
Google provided token info API and Azure always return scopes with access token.

Now the question to LinkedIn is how can we get it?